# Apply forEach function for array like object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I guess i have an issue. I tried to implement onchangedhandler method for input type file.

here is a piece of code

```
const { target: { files } } = event
       const filesToStore = []
       files.forEach(file => {
          filesToStore.push(file)
       })
console.log(filesToStore)
```

> But i have a problem. **TypeError: files.forEach is not a function**

i tried to clg files, and i see that it's an array like object, how to convert to array and store in filesToStore file value from input in my case?

**console.log(files)**

```
FileList {0: File, length: 1}
0: File {name: "176B8706.jpg", lastModified: 1556695382251, lastModifiedDate: Wed May 01 2019 10:23:02 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 7924152, …}
length: 1
__proto__: FileList
```

Comment: can you please log `files` and share it

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`files` is of type [`File​List`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) and it doesn't have a `forEach` extension method. You could [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it within an `[]` to convert it to an array of files:

```
[...files].forEach(file => { /* do something */ })
```

Or in your case, just this should be enough:

```
const filesToStore = [...files]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could take [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which takes an array like object and converts this object to an array.

```
filesToStore = Array.from(files);
```